# Keys of Dict are not enconded when I read from txt - Julia

Tags: json, dictionary, julia, readfile

I read a .txt file (it contains a Dict) but the keys of Dict are with errors. In the original file the names are right (ex: the file has "P. Cárdenas" but I got "P. C\xe1rdenas")

```
>> f = open("dict.txt", "r")
>> dict_maestro = JSON.parse(f)

>>Dict{String,Any} with 5 entries:
  "P. C\xe1rdenas"      => Dict{String,Any}("dist_tm"=>Any[Any[0.248, 0.074, 0.…
  "S. L\xf3pez"         => Dict{String,Any}("dist_tm"=>Any[Any[0.096, 0.082, 0.…
  "S. Cabrera"          => Dict{String,Any}("dist_tm"=>Any[Any[0.341, 0.094, 0.…
  "C. Mu\xf1oz"         => Dict{String,Any}("dist_tm"=>Any[Any[0.246, 0.073, 0.…
  "R. Bugue\xf1o"       => Dict{String,Any}("dist_tm"=>Any[Any[0.261, 0.068, 0.…
```

How can I get the right names?

Comment: It seems that you are getting escaped UTF characters. It does not necessarily mean they are incorrect but rather represented differently.

Comment: So, how can I transform the keys as I want? or configure my WS to read correctly?Tahnk you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you are reading the file as bytes, not as UTF strings. According to the answer to the linked duplicate question you should first convert the contents of the file to appropriately encoded strings and then parse it as JSON. This would go roughly the following way:

```
s = open("dict.txt", "r") do f
    utf16(readbytes(f))
end

dict_maestro = JSON.parse(s)
```

You can use `utf8` instead of `utf16` if this is the encoding you have in your file.

Comment: I tried what you wrote but the output was 
``` UndefVarError: readbytes not defined```

 I tried with readbytes! in this way 
```
s = open("dict.txt", "r")
data = UInt8[]
readbytes!(s, data, Inf)
close(s)

decode(data, "UTF-8")
```

but when a "accent mark" appear, the output show that the "byte sequence is invalid in source encoding or cannot be represented in target encoding"

Comment: You have to check what is the encoding of your file and use appropriate function (`utf8` or `utf16`). Maybe you have an error in the file and you will have to correct it first before reading it in....